# how to fetch all rows in u-sql in data lake in order by clause

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

While writing u-sql query I am using Order by clause FETCH clause is necessary to use but what should I write if don't want to fetch limited number of rows but all rows from rowsets. Thanks for help

Answer (score 4):

Since rowsets are unordered by definition, you should put the `ORDER BY` command when writing the final result to the output file

Syntax from the documentation:

```
OUTPUT @res
    TO "/output/Searchlog-having.csv"
    ORDER BY TotalDuration DESC
    USING Outputters.Csv();
```

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/data-lake-analytics-u-sql-get-started/

The `ORDER BY` in `SELECT` is relevant only when you're picking a subset of rows i.e. when you have a LIMIT clause

Answer (score 0):

This was not available at the time the question was asked, but you can try:

```
SELECT *
FROM @rowset
ORDER BY your_column OFFSET 0 ROWS;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
A.aa,
A.bb
FROM @rowset AS A
ORDER BY A.your_column
OFFSET 0 ROWS;

select * some tie wont work.. we will use all columns